# how to filter the list in REST API URL using Yes/No field

Tags: rest, api, filter, boolean, sharepoint-2013

I have done API for select and it is working fine.

When I tried to filter I used below query it is not working.

`?$filter=IsRequired eq 'Yes'`.

I am getting error:

> $filter=IsRequired eq 1" is not valid.

Kindly check and suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To filter the Yes/No field using REST API, you need use the filter below to achieve it.

```
$filter=IsRequired eq 1
```

REST API:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items?$select=Title&$filter=IsRequired eq 1
```